# I can't use apt-cache search find the tool that I found before

Tags: apt, kali-linux

Background story:

I installed `bettercap` on my working laptop by using `apt-get install` on my kali virtual machine install in VMWare Fusion for pen testing purpose.
However when I tried to install it in my own laptop with same Kali setup, I could not find it by using `apt-get install`, so I went for `apt-cache search`.

Interesting thing is it came up with nothing. Literally 0 prompting info.
How could I solve this issue ?

---

Special thank to @Kiwy

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82124/discussion-on-question-by-shan-huang-i-cant-use-apt-cache-search-find-the-tool).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your non-working environment isn’t configured to pull from the Kali repositories; you need to add

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then run `apt update`. This will allow you to install `bettercap` and any other Kali package you want to install.

See [the Kali documentation](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) for details, as mentioned in [Panki’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/464308/86440).

Comment: Stephen I can't thank you enough by marking yours as the final answer to my question, and I hope this can also help other people who might encounter the same issue as I did. 

Also I'd give special thanks to @kiwy for giving me loads of support and helping me editing the posts again and again. 

My apologies to anyone who might feel my previous responds are bit of offensive or inappropriate. 

Again, thank you Stephen, for making my day.

Comment: You are very welcome, and BTW welcome to Unix.SE! If you stick around you’ll find that this is quite a nice SE community ;-).

Comment: You're welcome. I hope this site will help you and that you will be able to help others as well.

Comment: @Kiwy Just realised Panki gave me the answer in the very beginning........

Answer (score 2):

You can only find or install packages that are in repositories which have been added to your system. Kali only comes with the Kali repository installed.

Read this for more information:

https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories

Also, @SivaPrasath is right. If you don't know what you're doing, you probably shouldn't be using Kali Linux.

I suggest you read up more about general Linux usage first.

Comment: @ShanHuang If we don't made assumption, how should we address to you ? like a beginner ? like an expert ? like a regular joe who doesn't know anything about computing ? We have to assume something, you're question is related almost certainly to Kali which most of the time is used by beginners because it looks cool. We have no choice according to your question who doesn't show any understanding of the problem that you're a beginner. If you're not a beginner, feel free to [edit] your question to add some logs debug step you've done and we will be glad to help. Take the time to read the [tour].

Comment: @Kiwy why do you think Kali looks cool in the first place? You doing something just for looking cool? Pls pay attention to my respond to yours I said there's no log or debug after you typing apt-cache search + keyword. And I think Panki is right , I suggest you read up more about general Linux usage first.

Comment: @ShanHuang "Most of the time on this site" my formulation was incomplete. There's log for everything. How about trying debug option for `apt-get` ? how about trying `apt` ? how about `dpkg-reconfigure -a` there's tone of thing you could try and tells us about but your only information is, nothing display on my screen. Even your explanation of what's working on another VM is unclear. Did you try the exact same disk image ? Did you try to install the same iso to another VM ? are you even using virtual machine ? how did you install anything ?

Comment: your question is an endless source of question which makes it IMO a bad question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok I've updated my question to more specific now, do you have any ideas now how to solve it?

Comment: @Panki just realised you gave me the right answer in the very beginning...

Answer (score 1):

You migh have inconsistencies between the Kali repositories and your setup, which is not surprising in Kali.

Failing to install it via APT, you can always install bettercap as it would have to be done in Debian (Kali is based on Debian - bettercap is a Kali-only package):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt–get install build–essential ruby–dev libpcap–dev
sudo gem install bettercap
sudo gem update bettercap
```

Comment: Thanks but still not working, here is the prompting msg:
`sudo apt-get update`
`reading package lists..done`
`sudo apt–get install build–essential ruby–dev libpcap–dev`
`reading package lists..done`
`Building dependency tree`
`Reading state information..done`
`Enable to locate package build–essential`
`Enable to locate package ruby–dev`
`Enable to locate package libpcap–dev`

Comment: So you have no repositories at all...reinstall the latest version of kali, not worth it trying to fix it.

Comment: yeah bro, I tried that also before I even posted it here. I literally had no clue that's why I ask. It used to work perfectly in my working laptop

Comment: I suggest you change your approach when coming here asking for help. You have been mildly hostile to people here, and are already making too many basic mistakes. Regards.

Comment: No problem, next time I will learn from my mistakes. But does this mean it's a dead-end now?